# How would I set a default value of HTML number input type?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel and am currently trying to pass form data to a database, but I'm getting an error that the fields I am trying to enter may not be null:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'assists' cannot be null
```

The way the form is set up, there will regularly be times where certain inputs are null,

```
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="player_id" value="{{ $player->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="game_id" value="{{ $game->id }}">
    <td>{{ $player->fn }} {{ $player->ln }}</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="goals" placeholder="goals"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="assists" placeholder="assists"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="tackles" placeholder="tackles"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="saves" placeholder="saves"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="yellows" placeholder="yellows"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="red" placeholder="red"></td>
</tr>
```

and that it almost the expected behavior. I figured the easiest way to fix this is to set the number input types default to 0, so it is passed to the database unless otherwise specified. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I would always have a `value=""` on text fields - why not `value="0"` on the number fields?

Comment: Better is to validate the incoming values in your processing php script (you have to do that anyway). If you know about what default values to use when handing out the html form, then you can also apply them when processing the filled form.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks. I didn't realize it could be so simple, thought that would override any value that was actually passed.

Comment: No it would not. in PHP you would have `value="{{ $player->goals }}"` and make that return 0 if no goals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714965/how-would-i-set-a-default-value-of-html-number-input-type#comment74473567_43714965) suggested, the simplest and most efficient is to use one of an `input` element's default attributes, `value`

```
<input type="number" name="goals" placeholder="goals" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you can achieve this.

Explicitly specify default column value in the model

```
class Game extends Model {
   protected $attributes = [
       'assists' => '0'
   ];
}
```

Comment: Note that this does _not_ really prevent the issue the OP sketches: if a user actively removes the value from the form then _still_ no value is transferred and the error occurs.

Comment: Then the second method would suffice

Comment: Sure, but in that case: why implement the _first_ option?#